Libavformat.so no longer found after upgrade
I just updated to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and Audacity can no longer find the FFmpeg Library. Specifically, libavformat.so in order to convert audio files. I have FFmpeg fully installed. Any thoughts?

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=noble&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libavformat.so says it's in libavformat-dev. Do you have that package installed?

I do! libavformat-dev is already the newest version (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5)

try to install old ffmpeg (or just a libs in your case):
curl -O https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.3.9.tar.gz
tar xf ffmpeg-3.3.9.tar.gz
cd ffmpeg-3.3.9
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
make
<a lot of warnings>

after that find libs:
~/ffmpeg-3.3.9$ find / -name "libavformat.so" 2>/dev/null
/home/user/ffmpeg-3.3.9/libavformat/libavformat.so

and create symlink:
ln -s /home/user/ffmpeg-3.3.9/libavformat/libavformat.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.57

